# Excel - Reference within a reference

Tags: excel

I may going up the wrong tree with this.

I have the following formula, that will replace the * with the range of sheets in the workbook, and SUM the values in cell B2 on each of the sheets:

```
=(SUM('*'!B2)/J2)/100
```

This works fine, however the formula doesn't retain the '*', it replaces it with the actual range, eg:

```
=(SUM('Period 1:Period 4'!B2)/J2)/100
```

So, is it possible to either:

1. Retain the '*' so that the formula doesn't update, and therefore remains dynamic should I add a new tab.
2. Add a reference into the reference. The first sheet will always be 'Period 1', however the end sheet will change from month to month, and will be 'Period x', where x is the value in cell J2. Is it possible to reference J2 within `=(SUM('Period 1:Period 5'!B2)/J2)/100`? `=(SUM('Period 1:Period [J2]'!B2)/J2)/100` or something similar?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this throws up an invalid cell reference error.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to do this is to create a 'sheet sandwich' with a `'Start'` and `'End'` sheet then the range is `=SUM('Start:End'!B2)`.  New sheets obviously have to be inserted between these to be included.

Note:not my solution, credit belongs to [SUM across multiple sheets with variable sheet name question](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/672368-sum-across-multiple-sheets-variable-sheet-name-question.html).